# Get all javascript code in the current page programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any simple way to get all javascript code in the current page programmatically?

For example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="userjs.js">
<script>
   //user's jscode here
</script>

</html>
```

And I need to put some code in `myjs.js`, and need to be able to get all javascript code, including the code in `userjs.js`, and the code in the script tag.

Actually getting the code inside the script tag is easy. But I'm stucked on how to get the code in `userjs.js`.

Comment: This is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Just (re-)download the userjs.js file as an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Then you can do whatever you like with the source.

Comment: What if the html and the userjs.js is from local disk in a test environment?

Comment: Then you would need to run your own HTTP server (a lightweight one would be sufficient). You could also override your browsers local file access restrictions but then you wouldn't want to surf real web pages with it so I don't recommend it.